# How do I optimize these scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, optimization, activerecord

We have several scopes in a single Model.
As the database grows, the scopes become unusable.

Using a scope with this type of query is where the problem begins:
where("devices.id IN (?)", ETC

Here are some of our scopes:

```rb
scope :reserved, -> { joins("INNER JOIN reservations ON (devices.ipaddress = reservations.ip)") }
scope :in_dhcp_range, -> {
    joins(
      "INNER JOIN dhcp_ranges ON (devices.ipaddress >= dhcp_ranges.start_ip AND devices.ipaddress <= dhcp_ranges.end_ip)"
    ).distinct
  }
scope :alternate_aws, -> {
    joins("INNER JOIN awssubnets ON (devices.ipaddress <<= awssubnets.cidr)").distinct
  }

scope :dhcp_full_calculation, -> {
    where("devices.id IN (?)",
      (Device.in_dhcp_range.select("devices.id") + Device.alternate_aws.select("devices.id")).uniq - Device.reserved)
  }
```

These scopes work when the database has only 50,000 records.  However, over 250k records, we have performance problems with this scope: dhcp_full_calculation

rails 5.2.3, ruby 2.6.3, using a postgres database

Comment: I believe the idea is good, but I get this error:  ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:select, :joins, :distinct]

Comment: excellent.  If you can set as an answer, I can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the overall performance issue is related to the calculation opertations that are happening outside of the database e.g.

```
(Device.in_dhcp_range.select("devices.id") + 
 Device.alternate_aws.select("devices.id")).uniq 
   - Device.reserved)
```

This is executing 3 queries and then using `Array` (or `Array` like) methods on the `ActiveRecord::Relation`s to return a list of the `Device`s to select. This will result in a lot of computation as well as a very large `IN` clause in the query (which at some point will exceed the number of characters allotted to SQL statement)

Instead you should place all of this work on the database itself using sub queries to build the where clause like so

```
scope :dhcp_full_calculation, -> {
  where.not(id: Device.reserved.select(:id) ).where(
    id: Device.select(:id).where(id: 
         Device.in_dhcp_range.select(:id) 
       ).or( 
         Device.select(:id).where( 
           id: Device.alternate_aws.select(:id) 
         ) 
       ) 
  )
}
```

This will generate a query akin to:

```
 SELECT 
   devices.*
 FROM 
   devices
 WHERE 
   devices.id NOT IN (
     SELECT devices.id FROM [YOUR RESERVED QUERY])
   AND  devices.id IN ( 
     SELECT devices.id 
     FROM devices
     WHERE 
       devices.id IN ( SELECT devices.id FROM [YOUR IN DHCP RANGE QUERY])
       OR devices.id IN ( SELECT devices.id FROM [YOUR ALTERNATE AWS QUERY])
     )
```